# Can't set CMYK "K" to "0"

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, cmyk

I've been asked to create a vector illustration where "K" must equal 0. I keep going to the shape fill, set it as 0 and all looks fine. But when I click back on the shape, the K value still shows up even as a small amount. See the snapshot below:

[image: cmyk values]

How can I set K to 0 and it stop moving?

Comment: Is your document CMYK?

Answer (score 5):

@Cai is right. To set your document to CMYK colour go to: **File → Document Color Mode → CMYK Color**.